# Мне нужно отобразить название переменной в инспекторе Unity, но при этом так, чтобы его нельзя было изменять в инспекторе, но можно в коде

Tags: c#, unity3d, переменные

У меня есть список пользовательских классов, имеющие 2 поля - название и скрипт. Собственно мне нужно сделать так, чтобы название поля BoosterField - Name я мог присваивать в коде, но так, чтобы в инспекторе его изменять никто не мог (но видел!) и так, чтобы эта переменная сохранялась после выхода из юнити, окончания PlayMode - то-есть был сереализованной. В списке ниже добавленных элементов почему-то нигде элементы списка не отображаются, они не добавляются.

Инспектор нужен лишь для того, чтобы давать ссылку на скрипт, а названия, чтобы понимать - куда какой класть. Что делать?

```
[SerializeField] private List<BoosterField> _listBoostersFields = new 
List<BoosterField>
{
    new BoosterField {Name = "Lake"},  new BoosterField() {Name = 
"Lighting"}
};

[Serializable]
public class BoosterField
{
    [SerializeField] private Booster _booster;
    [ReadOnly] public string Name;
    public Booster GetBooster => _booster;
}
```

Comment: [как задать хороший вопрос](//ru.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: Не понял, чего вы хотите, но, возможно, вам будет достаточно включить Debug режим инспектора? Вы хотите, чтобы в инспекторе отображалось значение переменной, но при этом поменять его было нельзя?

Comment: Да, так и хотел. Debug в принципе возможен, но не совсем удобен...